# Як перекласти "replica"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В якомусь фільмі почула, що "replica" переклали як "муляж" (була ситуація з несправжнім пістолетом). Завжди думала, що перекладається як "копія" чи "репліка". Почала перевіряти в мережі.

На порталі http://slovnenya.com:

replica
noun
1 відповідь, заперечення, копіювання, луна, репродукція.
2 відтворення, відтворювання, копія, репродукування, репродукція, розмноження.
3 копір, репродукція.

Гугл-перекладач видає результат "реплік".

Який варіант є правильним? Копія, репліка, реплік? Чи можна перекласти це слово як "муляж"?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Зазначу, що питання на цьому сайті мають стосуватися підбору/інтерпретації/аналізу **українських** слів. По Вашому запитанню неочевидно: чи Ви хочете вточнити значення англійського слова *replica*, чи Ви хочете вточнити значення українських слів *копія*/*муляж*/тощо. В першому випадку це запитання **не для нашого сайту** (ми не присвячені підбору/інтерпретації/аналізу *англійських* слів).</sub>

Майже ніколи не буває так, щоб слова з різних мов мали повністю індентичний набір значень і їхніх нюансів. Іншомовне слово *W₁* може перекладатися і українським словом *С₁*, і українським словом *С₂*, і українським словом *С₃* — залежно від контексту; при цьому якщо в якомусь контексті *W₁* переклали як *С₁*, то це не означає ані того, що його завжди треба перекладати як *С₁*, ані того, що *С₁* треба завжди перекладати назад як *W₁* — в інших контекстах нашому слову *С₁* краще може відповідати, наприклад, не іншомовне *W₁*, а іншомовне *W₂* чи *W₃*.

Слова *replica* і *муляж*, **на мою особисту думку**, мають майже протилежні значення. Слово *replica*, на мою особисту думку, найчастіше робить акцент на **точності копіювання** певних рис оригінального об'єкта або й навіть усіх його рис (replica — «an *exact* reproduction»<sup>[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/replica)</sup>, «a copy *exact in all details*»<sup>[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/replica)</sup>, «an *exact* copy»<sup>[C](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/replica), [W](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=replica&oldid=49379598#Noun)</sup>, «any *close or exact* copy or reproduction»<sup>[RH](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/replica)</sup>, «an *exact* copy or model»<sup>[O](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/replica)</sup>); в той час слово *муляж*, на мою особисту думку, зазвичай робить акцент, навпаки, на **нездатності копії повністю виконувати функції оригінального об'єкта** (СУМ-11 узагалі [каже](http://sum.in.ua/s/muljazh), що муляж — це завжди «зліпок із гіпсу, воску, парафіну тощо», хоча й відзначає повнорозмірність та зовнішню подобу). Хоча, звісно, **в певних контекстах** слова *replica* й *муляж* можна застовувати до тієї самої речі.

Як найкраще перекладати *replica* — залежить від конкретного контексту.